# Return Data based on Current Month, Date and Weekday Name

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

New to C#, Windows Forms, and Visual Studio.  I have searched around and really don't know where to start. I have successfully built a simple Windows Form that will display the Name of the Day, Current Month, Day using the DateTime.Today but now I need to figure out how to setup and store the values to pull based on those variables.  I was thinking about using arrays to store the data. Can someone let me know if I am on the right track.

```
 Array to store the Months and the data that is associated with each month
 Array to store the Weekday and the data that is associated with each weekday
 Array to store the Days and the data that is associated with each day
```

Then all I should have to do is figure out how to pull the data associated within the arrays then set it to the variables that will display in a textbox.  If anyone can point me in the right direction or possible link me to some good working examples that would be great.

UPDATE:

Here is what I used to grab the data I needed the just referenced it from the array I created

```
 int cDay = DateTime.Today.Day - 1;
 int cWeekDay = (int)System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(DateTime.Now) - 1;
 int cMonth = DateTime.Today.Month - 1;
```

Then I joined the data using

```
 months[cMonth] + weekdays[cWeekDay] + days[cDay];
```

Where months, weekdays, days where the arrays I created

Comment: What do you mean by "values to pull"? You haven't told us nearly enough about your data - where's it coming from? What kind of query facility does it support?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Jon,  sorry for now I just want static string values other than that I have not real clue the best way.

Comment: Please don't post answers in the question.

Comment: Jon Skeet said it best, you need to tell us about the data that is being pulled.  This will allow us to tell you how to setup the best way to hold the data.  Could be a class, List of classes or simply a array of strings but without know what the data is we are clueless.

Comment: Maybe, show us what your screen should look like?

Comment: Sorry I got it working awhile ago I just updated to show how I did it, everything has been working fine for a couple of months. Sorry for the confusion